# How can I issue multiple commands from a single query choice in Roll20?

Tags: roll20

I created a set of macros using the API to generate attributes for characters on Roll20 to refer to their pronouns for use in macros. I currently have it set up with 3 macros, each with 4 lines because I can't add multiple attributes with a single command.

How can I use a macro to query which set (male, female, or neutral) of pronouns I want to use? I know I should be able to do something like

```
?{Male, Female, or Neutral? | Male,#Pronouns_M | Female,#Pronouns_F | Neutral,#Pronouns_N}
```

And that should work, but I'd rather have it where the *contents* of those sub-macros are in the main one and delete the sub-macros. Problem is, each of the sub macros is 4 lines such as #Pronouns_F

```
!setattr --sel --subjective|'she'

!setattr --sel --objective|'her'

!setattr --sel --PossessiveA|'her'

!setattr --sel --PossessiveP|'hers'
```

Is this a thing I can do or do I have to settle for the sub macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a little more difficult than I anticipated but that's fine. <s>Was still not able to issue multiple commands from a single query choice</s> but I did solve the issue in the OP as it turns out I can assign multiple attributes from a single command and it was user error before (though I'm not sure what I did wrong).

Here's the final working macro (which must be saved as an ability due to HTML replacement characters breaking in macros):

`?{Male, Female, Neutral, or Monster? | Male,!setattr --sel --subjective&#124;'he' --objective&#124;'him' --PossessiveA&#124;'his' --PossessiveP&#124;'his' | Female,!setattr --sel --subjective&#124;'she' --objective&#124;'her' --PossessiveA&#124;'her' --PossessiveP&#124;'hers' | Monster,!setattr --sel --subjective&#124;'it' --objective&#124;'it' --PossessiveA&#124;'its' --PossessiveP&#124;'its' | Neutral,!setattr --sel --subjective&#124;'they' --objective&#124;'them' --PossessiveA&#124;'their' --PossessiveP&#124;'theirs'}`

And here's multiple commands from one query! Thanks to GiGs on the [Roll20 Forums](https://app.roll20.net/forum/permalink/8900454/) for showing me how to do it.

```
?{Male,Female, or Neutral?|Male,!setattr --sel --subjective|'he'
!setattr --sel --objective|'him'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveA|'his'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveP|'his'|Female,!setattr --sel --subjective#'she'
!setattr --sel --objective#'her'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveA#'her'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveP#'hers'|Neutral,!setattr --sel --subjective|'they'
!setattr --sel --objective|'them'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveA|'their'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveP|'theirs'|Monster,!setattr --sel --subjective|'it'
!setattr --sel --objective|'it'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveA|'its'
!setattr --sel --PossessiveP|'its'}
```